# Evaluating Improper Integrals with Residues - don't think I'm calculating the residues properly

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I have to evaluate the integrals $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2}+p^{2}}$, for $p > 0$, and $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^{2}+p^{2})^{2}}$, for $p > 0$ using residues.

For the first integral, we have two simple poles, one at $x = -ip$ and one at $x=ip$. So, I used the formula $\displaystyle res_{a}f = res_{a}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P(a)}{Q^{\prime}(a)}$ to calculate them. (First off, is this formula correct?)

I got that $\displaystyle res_{-ip} = \frac{1}{(x^{2}+p^{2})^{\prime}}\Large \vert_{x=-ip}$ $ \displaystyle = \frac{i}{2p}$. However, according to Maple, the resdiue at $x = -ip$ is $0$. Why the discrepancy?

I wound up getting $\displaystyle res_{ip} = \frac{-i}{2p}$, so that my integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2}+p^{2}} = 0$, because when you add the two residues that I got together, and then multiply them by $2\pi i$, you get $0$. According to Maple, that should be the value of this integral, but it would appear that I am getting there using incorrect residues. Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

For the second integral, I'm getting the residues $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{4ip^{3}}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4ip^{3}}$, respectively, for the residues at the $2$nd order poles $x = -ip$ and $x=ip$, when according to Maple, I should be getting $0$ for each.

So, I am really extremely confused about what is going wrong, and I really need to know how to properly apply residues to evaluating integrals, so I need someone to correct what I am doing and steer me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the contour you use to integrate over? Whatever contour you use it will not enclose both of the poles.

Comment: @Winther, it's not a contour integral. It's using residues to evaluate a real improper integral. The way I wrote the problem is exactly how it appears in my homework.

Comment: I was reffering to the mistake here: "because when you add the two residues that I got together, and then multiply them by $2\pi i$, you get $0$"

Comment: @Winther, I am not sure that I follow. I was not given a path to integrate around. Am I supposed to arbitrarily choose one?

Comment: The residues you have found look correct. However to convert residues to the value of an integral you are using Cauchy's theorem which says that the integral around a contour is equal to the sum of the residues inside the contour. To compute your integral we fix $R$ and integrate over $[-R,R]$ and then over a semi-circle from $z=R$ to $z=-R$. This will enclose only one of the poles. When taking $R\to\infty$ we can show that the integral along the semi-circle goes to $0$ while the integral over $[-R,R]$ becomes the integral you are after.

Comment: @Winther, okay...I thought there was a theorem though that said that you could just add up the residues and multiply the result by $2 \pi i$. Also, if my residues are correct, then why is Maple giving me different answers?

Comment: @Winther, see: http://faculty.up.edu/wootton/Complex/Chapter11.pdf

Comment: Can't help you with the Maple result. Maybe it's some bug in the symbolic implementation or in the way you try to compute it?! Try doing it with $p$ being a real number say $p=1$ and see if it works. In the note you link notice what Theorem 1.1 says *"...are the singularities in the **upper half plane**"...* This means to only include residues with imaginary part $> 0$.

Comment: @Winther, so the overall integral should only equal $2\pi i \cdot -\frac{i}{2p}$ for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+p^{2})}dx$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (and the other integral becomes $\frac{\pi}{p^3}$).

Comment: @Winther, huh. Interesting. So, I don't have to fix $R$ and integrate over $[-R, R]$, etc.? I can just apply this theorem, and I've got it?

Comment: Yes. You can use the theorem you linked to - just be careful about only including the residues that are in the upper half plane. What I tried to explain above (with the $[-R,R]$ thing) is the way that theorem is proven.

Comment: @Winther, gotcha. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: @Winther, actually don't you mean the other integral becomes $\frac{\pi}{2p^{3}}$?

Comment: Yes you are right.